# State design pattern - Passing Objects

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a state design pattern implementation with 3 states:

```
State1::DoTask(){...}

State2::DoTask(){...}

State3::DoTask(){...}
```

These all 3 states need to use 2 classes already instanced

e.g.

```
State1::DoTask()
{ 
    sensor->GetData(...)
    server->Send(buf,size)
}
```

How is the best way to pass these 2 class pointer objects to the State1, State2 and State3?

I thought in two options:

**1)** The Sensor and Server class could be a singleton:

```
State1::DoTask()
{
    sensor = Sensor::GetInstance();
    server = Server::GetInstance();
    ....
}
```

**2)** Passing by using other object to hold the class pointer:

```
class ComClasses
{
    Sensor *sensor;
    Server *server;
}

State1::DoTask(ComClasses *c)
{
    ....
}
```

In your opinion, how is the best method? Is there a better solution?

Best regards,

Comment: Why not pass the pointers as parameters to `DoTask`? Why not references instead of pointers?

Comment: Yes, it could be a reference. But this do not solve the answer. Thanks

Comment: You asked if there is a better solution, references are a better solution if the pointers should never be null. That said, I didn't give the advice as an answer, but a comment. Did you consider passing the references as arguments to `DoTask` as I suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it when you initialize the states.

```
State1 state1( sensor, server );
State2 state2( sensor, server );
State3 state3( sensor, server );
```

And then the DoTask interface method, which is your client method, should not care about the implementation of each individual State class. Each state will implement it using their own information.

```
state1.DoTask();
...
```

To comment on your solutions, I think I'd prefer the singleton.
If you find a new object that needs to be used by each state you will probably keep adding parameters. Your second solution solves that but you will then, maybe, pass objects to states that won't need to use them.

But probably initialization is best.

Comment: Hi Aslg,  I will add more objects that they will not be used by every state.  Suppose that I add more 4 objects, passing they by reference would take too many function arguments. I think i will with singletons. Best regards :)